# Raphaeljs's 'getPointAtLength' returns linear values for a quadratic bezier curve created using 'T' SVG commands

Tags: svg, raphael

I'm using Raphaeljs version 2.1.2.  I've create a bezier curved path based on the following values:

```
M1052,141T1186,63T1281,206T1019,241
```

The important part here are not the values but the command: I'm using the `T` SVG command to create a curved line between the points. The path appears fine on the screen, connecting the points in a curved line. However, when I use the function `getPointAtLength` to get a point on this line, I get a point on what the path would look like had I used the `L` command and not the `T`; in other words, I get the points that appear on imaginary straight lines connecting the various points above, and not the the points on the curved line that appears on the screen.

### After more than 10 hours of trying to figure this out with no success, any idea will be greatly appreciated.

after a few hours... :

I simplified the part of the code which creates the problem, now reduced to having the "glow" part of the curve in straight lines, while at the same time the very same path is shown in bezier curved form:

```
var r = Raphael('homeTop');
var animationPath = r.path("M1052,141T1186,63T1281,206T1019,241");
animationPath.glow();
```

Now this code on fiddle works as it should.. that's what I don't understand, why exactly the same code doesn't work somewhere else... !

Comment: Could you please provide some sample code?

Comment: Hi Carlo, Thanks for your quick reply.  My code is part of a single-page-application, rather complex, so I tried to recreate a fiddle, but surprisingly the fiddle works... as opposed to the original code which doesn't work...  I've tried to minimize and simplify the original code as much as possible, making it almost the same as the fiddle, and it still doesn't work.  Using F12 on chrome I debugged the code and another strange thing is that when I call the "glow" function on the curved path - I get straight lines connecting the 'T' points just as returned by getPointAtLength() !... :-(

Comment: ...just to make it clearer - the same object which created the curved path, when calling 'glow' on it - show straight lines and not curved ones.  I get both curved lines and straight lines of the screen... and I just don't know what to look for anymore, I tried any possible attribute with no clue on what could cause this...  Thanks again.

Comment: Could you at least provide the URL of the page?

Comment: Thanks again for replying almost instantly! the problem is the that the project is offline and because it's a complex application involving also a DB, it isn't simple to upload it... :-(  If I won't be able to find any other path then I will upload it and share the URL.  In the meanwhile, if you have any idea on what could possibly make a curved path into one that is made of straight lines, I'll be happy to hear :-)...  (the glow() is called immediately after creating the curved path, so I suppose the problem lies not the in the creation of the path but something in the background...)

Comment: OK, I was able to reduce the code to minimum... added it to the main post on top... thanks !

Comment: I can still not reproduce the problem (tested on Firefox and Chromium). http://jsfiddle.net/4M5wu/ Could you please edit that fiddle to make the problem visible? Are you sure you are using the last version available of the library?

Comment: Thanks man... I'm trying... but the fiddle works well, the curved path glows as it should... I can't reproduce the problem and I can't rule out anything on my code that may influence the problem (in my code I put it in the beginning of the page before anything else). Perhaps I need to sleep over this... Thanks again, sorry I couldn't reproduce the problem.

Comment: I managed to recreate the problem in a simple single file: the point is that that the "glow" path is not the curve, here it is: http://studiomooza-001-site1.smarterasp.net/raphael.html .  Thanks again !  (the 'raphael.js' file was copied from this URL: https://raw.github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/master/raphael-min.js)

Comment: I removed the jquery link, please ignore the reference to it in the previous comment, and also added a usage of the 'getPointAtLength()' that shows how the function returns a value positioned on the linear path and not on the curved path.  Thanks.

Comment: It's a bug, a regression bug, because in version 2.1.0 it was fine. [File it](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/issues), in the meantime you can switch to the version 2.1.0.

Comment: you're right.  I just figured this out.  Here are links to the same file with version 2.1.2 and version 2.1.1 showing the difference: http://studiomooza-001-site1.smarterasp.net/raphael2.1.1.html  http://studiomooza-001-site1.smarterasp.net/raphael2.1.2.html.  I will file it now.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug of the library, the script you download from the [`master` branch](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael) is [affected](http://jsfiddle.net/4M5wu/2/), but the one on the [`v2.1.2` branch](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/tree/v2.1.2) is [fine](http://jsfiddle.net/4M5wu/4/). Also, on older versions, such 2.1.0 the issue isn't showing up.

So, why on `master` is it broken? The culprit is [commit ad15a1c](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/commit/ad15a1c9b05200c9f042807527eabcaabc5fecc4), which was meant to solve the [bug #629](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/issues/629), which is first experienced here on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13043217/raphael-path2curve-does-not-honor-the-original-path). The problem is the patch wasn't complete, it has been fixed on [commit 3bc12c3](https://github.com/tomasAlabes/raphael/commit/3bc12c3d8c29932403e495a53223dcb4396243e5), which is on the `v2.1.2` branch.

So using the script at the URL https://raw.github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/v2.1.2/raphael-min.js it should work.